# Hangfire server in .Net Worker Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I am trying to start Hangfire server in .Net Worker Service using example:
[Configure Hangfire dashboard in a worker service in .Net 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71492137/configure-hangfire-dashboard-in-a-worker-service-in-net-5) answer by **Ruslan Gilmutdinov** https://stackoverflow.com/users/1734655/ruslan-gilmutdinov but following code

```
using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WorkerServiceHangfire
{
    public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
    
            public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
                {
                    builder.Configure(app =>
                    {
                        app.UseRouting();
    
                        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
                        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                        {
                            endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard();
                        });
                    });
                })
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddHangfire(conf => conf.UseSqlServerStorage("connection string"));
                        services.AddHangfireServer();
    
                        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    });
        }
}
```

gives error at **builder.Configure(app =>** line:

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method
> 'OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure(IServiceCollection,
> IConfiguration)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the
> type arguments explicitly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You have to include the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` wich contains `WebHostBuilderExtensions` an extension class that among other extension methods contains also the one you are trying to use:
`public static IWebHostBuilder Configure(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder, Action<IApplicationBuilder> configureApp)`

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`

Comment: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting is included.
My usings:

using Hangfire;

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

Comment: Just for test can you try to edit the .csproj and add: <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"></FrameworkReference>
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: Done, but same error :(

Comment: I have seen that you have updated the question with all the includes but `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` is missing, is possible that you have confused it with `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;`? you need them both

Comment: Now it works !!! Thank you so much!!! Mixed up Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting and Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting